# What is being sent via cookie from my browser, that might trigger a POST method versus a GET method from Paypal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the Paypal Classic API via Sandbox as shown in [Railscast 143](http://railscasts.com/episodes/143-paypal-security) in Rails 4x and Ruby 2x deployed on Heroku.

The User should be able to add purchases to a cart, and upon clicking a button is routed to Paypal to complete the transaction.  Once the purchase is completed, a payment notification is sent to the notification_url, and then the browser is redirected to the return_url, which is the same page the user was on before.  I'm using Railscasts' SSL to encrypt.

Everything works except the return URL.

I've noticed that for any new browser in a new computer, after the purchase is completed on Paypal, the browser does not return to the proper URL.  However, once I manually go back to the last page on my site and refresh, showing the purchase has been made properly, I can go through the process again to buy another item, and the return url works.  The 2nd time around, the Paypal window looks a bit different, because it remembers the user from the last transaction.

Even if I clear cookies and all history for a browser, Paypal will still remember and the method will succeed.

When I look at my logs, I see that the difference between success and failure is that in the success, there is a POST method being sent to my return URL, which is Projects/purchase.

In the failed version, there is a GET method being sent to the return URL, which is wrong.

Here is the log of a success: https://gist.github.com/allenwlee/1f51a4dac884ba25ba5f

Here is the log of a failure: https://gist.github.com/allenwlee/dff86f7de2f16951f512

Here's all my relevant code:  https://gist.github.com/allenwlee/9e24ae7384a0f5e9bff2

Comment: Hi Allen,

I cannot reproduce a scenario where RM=2 is being respected on my machine - no matter which browser.

As such, I will check with our Devs and need to get back to you.

In the meantime, please try and integrate with using the GET parameters upon loading the return URL. This should work more reliably, as I've seen some browsers ignoring the FORM POST being requested.

Comment: Thanks, will do.  The method I'm using is five years old (from an old Railscast episode), in which a POST method was kind of monkey patched onto the usual GET method, so that may be the source of the problem.

Comment: No worries, as long as we cannot get PP to send the data in a POST, it's a PP problem and I intend to get that fixed.
However, the RM variable has been a recurring pain point and a HTTP GET seems to be more reliable in the long run.